# How do you say "How am I supposed to X"?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I know/think that ~ばいい can be used, ex.

> How am I supposed to deal with this?
>
> どう扱えばいい？

But is there another way to say it? Maybe something involving はず?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're looking for another expression (i.e., do you have a specific situation in mind?) or just curiosity?

Comment: I'm trying to translate something where this is being asked in a very demanding, desperate way. For some reason I feel like ばいい doesn't carry across enough of those feelings, though I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Perhaps いったい could help convey those feelings. I believe the construct is correct though. I am not aware of anything else.

Comment: どうやって is the first expression that springs to my mind

Comment: I think the problem is no one else really knows how demanding your words are, what the situation is, whom are you talking to, what is your intonation, and what nuance you are trying to convey (e.g. are you complaining it is too demanding, or are you writing a troubleshooting manual to give others a guidance). There are probably dozens of ways to translate this and unless you give more context, people will agree with what you suggested first. スタックエクスチェンジでの正しい訪ね方は何ですか？ (could also be "how am i supposed to ask questions on SE?")

Comment: At least I think 扱う is closer to "operate" or "handle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I still don't really understand the exact situation you're imagining, but maybe something like

> いったいどうしたらいいの？！もうわけわっかんないよ…

is desperate enough for you? (At least, I can imagine someone crying and saying it...)

Comment: I like it so much :D

Comment: いったい does give it the most 'kick' as another comment suggested, and ending it with の or んだ(よ) brings it out even more so thanks for the example! べき as user4092 suggested would have probably worked too.

Answer (score 1):

The closest phrase to "be supposed to do" is …することになっている, and you can say どう扱うことになっている(のだろうか)？. However, if the matter doesn't have enough reproducibility, it's not necessarily a useful expression. In that sense, どう扱えばいい or どう扱うべき are reasonable after all.

Answer (score 1):

Your example (どう扱えばいい？) is about as close to "How am I supposed to deal with this?" as you can get.

Here are some related phrases:

> What should I do?
> どうすればいい？
>
> What is the best way to (do something)?
> （何かする）のに一番いい方法は何でしょうか。
>
> There's no way I could do that.
> できるはずはない。